# Handle clicks to button in tab bar controller header

Tags: ios, event-handling, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tab bar controller with a number of tabs/views. I have added a "Help" bar button item to the tab bar controller's  top navigation bar.

How do I handle clicks of this button, ideally depending on which view I am in at the time?

I am simply going to pop up an alert when it is clicked, ie. No navigation required.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this "help" tab should not change its behaviour depending on context, i.e., what tab was previously selected. The user will get confused because the content will not be constant.

If you raise a "pop up alert" when the tab is selected, this also seems like a basis for rejection because of bad UX. Selecting a tab should display a new view for that tab. You'd also have to deal with how to move the user back to the previous tab silently, and/or not change the selected tab index. Again, this is troublesome UX.

If you insist on going with this design -- which I believe will get your app rejected -- you can use a [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate) to control the behaviour of the `UITabBarController`.

I recommend you change your design instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working. I think you misunderstood: I have a tab bar control which operates normally by pushing views based on the tab selected. I simply wanted a help button on the right of the navigation bar that would open an alert with information about the tab you happen to be in at the time. I have done it like this:

In `viewDidAppear` of each view pushed by the tab bar controller:

```
UIBarBarButtonItem *helpButton = [[UIBarBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(helpButtonPressed))];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=helpButton;
```

I then have the `helpButtonPressed` function to handle the button click, in my case by popping up and alert with some help info regarding the tab.